# Laravel Query scopes for hotel reservation system with multiple rooms on edit method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a hotel reservation system, where **user/admin** can select **multiple rooms** for reservation.

I am facing a problem in the `edit` functionality. I am looking for help and suggestions on how to make this right.

My schema.

Rooms:

```
room_number
price
reserved (Boolean)
maintenance (Boolean)
```

Reservations:

```
customer_id
checkin
checkout
```

Reservation_Room

```
room_id
reservation_id
TotalPrice
```

Query scope on rooms:

```
public function scopeIsNotReserved($query)
{
    return $query->where('reserved', false);
}
```

Relationship Reservation Model:

```
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class);
}
```

The actual problem is.

I cannot use `IsNotReserved query scope` while editing a reservation, because it won't pass the value to the selected options.

I would like to pass all the rooms that are not reserved except this `reservation_id` (See `$roomId`).

My controller edit function looks like this:

```
$reservation = Reservation::findOrFail($id);

$customers = Customer::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

// Currently not doing anything with this query.

```
$roomId = $reservation->rooms()->pluck('rooms.id')->toArray();
```

Getting All Rooms

```
$rooms = Room::IsNotOnMaintenance()->get();
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you wanna do, can you be more clearer?

Comment: I am passing rooms that needs to be selected from a reservation form. 
When that form is saved three rows are affected or mutated. When reservation is made, the room reserved is updated to true, reservation table is created along with reservation_room.
Everything is working fine when adding new reservation. 
Now I want to edit this reservation. Only those rooms are listed which are not reserved.  I would like to pass all the rooms that are not reserved except the ones that i choose or filter, in this case against these id's
$roomId = $reservation->rooms()->pluck('rooms.id')->toArray();

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to get all unreserved rooms and then filter out those in `$roomId`?
Can you try this: `Room::IsNotReserved()->except($roomId)`

Comment: #Remul

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::except()

Comment: Sorry you have to use it on a collection:
`Room::IsNotReserved()->get()->except($roomId);`
If you want to use it on the query builder you could use:
`Room::IsNotReserved()->whereNotIn('id', $roomId)->get();`

Comment: This will not work as the IsNotReserved pulls a collection of those rooms whose reserved = false.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as I understood you, you want to use the scope but pass an array of id's which you want to be excluded from the query result? If so I will post an example of that scope:

```
public function scopeIsNotReserved($query, $exclusions)
{
    return $query->where('reserved', false)->whereNotIn('id', $exclusions);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and some other methods before posting it on stackoverflow.

$roomId = $reservation->rooms()->pluck('rooms.id')->toArray();

gives an array of two items

array:2 [▼
  0 => 7
  1 => 10
]

Room::IsNotReserved($roomId)->get();

the query scope above is somehow not working with it.

Comment: When you say not working, you mean it gives you bad results or an error?

Comment: it doesn't give any error. it just gives the result where room reserved is true, and doesn't give or show $roomId array.

Comment: Can you give us your migrations where this `reserved` field is

Comment: Please refer to the question it's there.